# MvcContrib.Grid renders extra hidden input in column

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, checkbox, http-post, hidden

In the following truncated cshtml excerpt i'm using a Grid to build a table:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("DeleteSelected", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.Grid(Model).Columns(column => {
        column
            .For(x => x.CreationTime).Format("{0:g}");
        column
            .For(x => x.OtherPropery);
        column
            .For(x => x.YetAnotherProperty);
        column
            .For(x => Html.CheckBox(x.IdThatICanUseToGrabModels, new {@class = "isSelectedCheck"}))
            .Header(@<div><input type="checkbox" id="isSelectedHeader"/></div>);
    });
```

When I submit my grid via form POST I'd like to be able to determine which rows were selected and act accordingly in my controller logic.  The last `column.For(...)` statement creates a checkbox input and a hidden input.

Apparently this is the expected behavior.  Since the two inputs get the same name, how is one expected to loop over the `FormCollection` object and get out the correct values?  Each key (named `x.IdThatICanUseToGrabModels`) can end up with more than one value.

How do other people get past this?

thanks,

brian

Answer (score 2):

The CheckBox/CheckBoxFor helpers are intended to be used with boolean properties on your view model. So:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public DateTime CreationTime { get; set; }
    public string OtherProperty { get; set; }
    public string YetAnotherProperty { get; set; }
    public bool IdThatICanUseToGrabModels { get; set; }
}
```

and then:

```
@Html.Grid(Model).Columns(column =>
{
    column.For(x => x.CreationTime).Format("{0:g}");
    column.For(x => x.OtherProperty);
    column.For(x => x.YetAnotherProperty);
    column
        .Custom(@<text>@Html.CheckBox("values", item.IdThatICanUseToGrabModels)</text>)
        .Header(@<div><input type="checkbox" id="isSelectedHeader"/></div>);
})
```

and finally:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DeleteSelected(bool[] values)
{
    ...
}
```

You could also have a hidden id corresponding to the boolean value (you will have a couple consisting of an id and a boolean property which will allow you in the controller action to know which id is selected).

Comment: This looks way better than my solution but I'm confused about your `IdThatICanUseToGrabModels` property.  Should that be an `int` with a seperate property `bool IsSelected` or do I misunderstand something?

Answer (score 0):

So for now I've solved it like this:

```
column
    .For(x => Html.Raw("<input name="+x.AMPExamNumber.ToString()+" type=\"checkbox\" />"))
    .Header(@<div><input type="checkbox" id="isSelectedHeader"/></div>);
```

I can then grab the key-value pairs out of the `FormCollection` object use them to select my objects from the DB.

This seems awful.  If anyone has a better solution please post, lest I am forced to flag this as the solution...